# Flutter Alice package on within existing context above Bottom Navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, alice

//Alice package open Http calls inspector in new page i want to open within existing project above bottom navigation bar.I think we need to BuildContext so that it will not navigate to new page but it has no paramter to pass context so it is creating new page.Any solution?/// Opens Http calls inspector.

````
//This will navigate user to the new fullscreen page where all listened http calls can be viewed.
void showInspector() {
  \_aliceCore.navigateToCallListScreen();
}

/// Opens Http calls inspector. This will navigate user to the new fullscreen
void navigateToCallListScreen() {
  final context = getContext();
  if (context == null) {
    AliceUtils.log(
      'Cant start Alice HTTP Inspector. Please add NavigatorKey to your '
      'application',
    );
    return;
  }
  if (!\_isInspectorOpened) {
    \_isInspectorOpened = true;
    Navigator.push\<void\>(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =\> AliceCallsListScreen(this, \_aliceLogger),
      ),
    ).then((onValue) =\> \_isInspectorOpened = false);
  }
} ```


//I want Alice package open Http calls inspector in same page where bottom navigation bar exist. i want to open within existing project above bottom navigation bar.
````